TypeError: chai.deployed is not a function
Error:
PS D:\SimpleStorage> npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js
TypeError: chai.deployed is not a function
    at main (D:\SimpleStorage\scripts\deploy.js:11:16)
PS D:\SimpleStorage> 

deploy.js:
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    // Fetching the byte code and ABI
    const Chai = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("chai");

    // Deploying an instance of our smart contract
    const chai = await Chai.deploy();

    // Waiting for the contract to be deployed
    await chai.deployed();

    console.log("Deployed contract address:", chai.address);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });

hardhat.config.js:
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.24",
};


You should use waitForDeployment() instead of deployed(), because deployed() is replaced with waitForDeployment() in the newer versions of Hardhat.
Also, you need to replace chai.address with await chai.getAddress().
So, in your deploy.js file, replace:
// Waiting for the contract to be deployed
await chai.deployed();

console.log("Deployed contract address:", chai.address);

with:
// Waiting for the contract to be deployed
await chai.waitForDeployment();

console.log("Deployed contract address:", await chai.getAddress());

